# Adding new npm dependencies to a Amazon Linux 2 Node.js instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am pushing a code change that adds new npm dependencies (@tensorflow/tfjs), on an application deployed by EB. The platform is Node.js 16 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.8.7, and in a deprecated state. I get the following error in eb-engine.log:

```
2023/11/01 22:19:38.573395 [INFO] Using npm v8
2023/11/01 22:19:38.573411 [INFO] Running command /bin/su webapp -c npm --omit=dev install
2023/11/01 22:20:12.128248 [INFO] npm WARN tar ENOENT: Cannot cd into '/var/app/staging/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/app/staging/node_modules/yauzl/package.json'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/app/staging/node_modules/yocto-queue/license'
```

What I've tried so far:

- Taking node_modules out of .gitignore and including that with the commit. That was what I think https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-dependencies.html#nodejs-platform-nodemodules (Including Node.js dependencies in a node_modules directory) was implying I should do, but I got the same error with "Cannot cd into...".

This problem is preventing me from making an important deployment by end of this week, any help would be greatly appreciated!